# Sequelize create with associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have been trying to define a relationship between 3 tables and then create them all in one create function. For some reason, while creating the 3 models, the linking IDs (foreign keys) are undefined and are not passing on. Here are the associations:

Person.js:

```
models.person.Lead = models.person.hasMany(models.lead, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "person_id"
});
```

Lead.js:

```
models.lead.Person = models.lead.belongsTo(models.person, {foreignKey: 'person_id'});

models.lead.Sealant_customer = models.lead.hasOne(models.sealant_customer, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: 'lead_id'
})
```

sealantCustomer.js:

```
models.sealant_customer.Lead = models.sealant_customer.belongsTo(models.lead);
```

The build function:

```
let sealantCustomer = models.sealant_customer.build({
                address: body.address,
                city: body.city,
                roof_size: body.roofSize,
                last_sealed: body.lastSealed,
                existingSealant: body.existingSealant,
                leaks_freq: body.leaksFrequency,
                floor: body.floor,
                elevator: body.elevator,
                panels: body.panels,
                home_type: body.homeType,
                urgency: body.urgency,
                next_step: body.nextStep,
                more_info: body.moreInfo,
                lead: {
                  site,
                  url: body.url,
                  date,
                  ip: body.ip,
                  person: {
                    name: body.name,
                    email: body.email,
                    phone: body.phone,
                    date,
                    city: body.city ? body.city : undefined,
                    address: body.address ? body.address : undefined,
                  }
                }
              }, {
                include: [{
                  model: models.lead,
                  association: models.sealant_customer.Lead,
                  include: [{
                    model: models.person,
                    association: models.lead.Person
                  }]
                }]
              })
```

The outputted object is good except for the fact that lead_id and person_id are nulls (Each model has its own ID, but not the associated model's id). I also should note there are no validation errors and the data is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library has a bug in the build function as far as I can tell. Same syntax with create worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize v6, the association identifier in the include section is not valid. Otherwise, this build function should properly work.